# Read EXIF data of an Image in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, exif

How to read EXIF data of an Image in a blackberry device using code. I have used [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) in android. Is there something similar in blackberry.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really tried this, but my best guess would be [getMetaData()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#getMetaData%28%29)
 in EncodedImage, which returns a [MetaDataControl](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/control/MetaDataControl.html):

> MetaDataControl is used to retrieve metadata information included
>   within the media streams. A MetaDataControl object recognizes and
>   stores metadata and provides XML-like accessor methods to retrieve
>   this information.